# INT field - String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

first-time poster, long-time fan.
I've looked at all the other answers on this topic and can't find anything that solves the problem.

I have some SQL that returns a matrix of qualifications by region using a dynamic pivot. I have the code working correctly, bringing back all rows, but now I want to use a filter.

The errant code is in the WHERE clause: `T3.TrainingTypeID = ' + @TrainingID + '`
If I hard code a value for `T3.TrainingTypeID` (this is an alias for `tlkpTrainingType.ID`), (200, say), I get one row returned, which is what I want but if I assign the same value to variable `@TrainingID INT`, I get the above error message.
I have checked the datatype of `tlkpTrainingType.ID` and it is definitely INT (And `Select Max(Len(TlkpTrainingType.ID)) From TlkpTrainingType` returns 3).

I'm not sure I understand triggers all that well, but given that I'm just reading from the DB, am I right in thinking it's not relevant here?

Am I missing something completely obvious?
All insights appreciated, I'm a relative newbie!

Here is my code, the relevant WHERE clause is near the bottom:

```
DECLARE @TrainingID AS INT, @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @cols3 AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(tlkpRegion.RegionName) 
            FROM tlkpRegion FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(tlkpRegion.RegionName) + ',0) as' + QUOTENAME(tlkpRegion.RegionName)       FROM tlkpRegion FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @cols3 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', SUM(' + QUOTENAME(tlkpRegion.RegionName) + ') as ' + QUOTENAME(tlkpRegion.RegionName)       FROM tlkpRegion FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

SET @TrainingID = 200;

SET @query = '

SELECT
    T3.TrainingType,
    T3.TrainingTypeID,
    ' + @cols3 + '

    FROM

        (SELECT
        tlkpTrainingType.Name AS TrainingType,
        tlkpTrainingType.ID AS TrainingTypeID, ' + @cols2 + '

        FROM
        tlkpTrainingType
            LEFT OUTER JOIN

            (SELECT
            TrainingType,
            TrainingTypeID, ' + @cols + '

            FROM

                (SELECT
                R0.RegionID,
                R0.RegionName,
                T0.TrainingType,
                T0.TrainingTypeID,
                T0.CountQuals

                FROM

                    tlkpRegion AS R0

                    LEFT OUTER JOIN

                    (SELECT        
                        tlkpTrainingType.Name AS TrainingType, 
                        tlkpTrainingType.ID AS TrainingTypeID,
                        tlkpTrainingType.ID AS CountQuals,
                        tlkpRegion.RegionName,
                        tlkpRegion.RegionID

                        FROM            

                        tblTechnicianTraining
                        INNER JOIN tlkpTrainingType ON tlkpTrainingType.ID = tblTechnicianTraining.TrainingTypeRef 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblTechnician ON tblTechnician.TechnicianID = tblTechnicianTraining.TechnicianRef
                        INNER JOIN tlkpRegion ON tlkpRegion.RegionID = tblTechnician.RegionRef 

                        WHERE 

                        tlkpTrainingType.Deleted = 0 AND 
                        tblTechnician.CurrentlyEmployed = 1 AND 
                        tblTechnicianTraining.ExpiryDate > GetDate()
                    ) AS T0 
                    ON T0.RegionID = R0.RegionID
                ) 
                AS T1

                PIVOT

                (COUNT(CountQuals)
                    for RegionName IN (' + @cols + ')
                ) AS P

            GROUP BY
            TrainingType,
            TrainingTypeID, ' + @cols + ') AS T2
            ON T2.TrainingTypeID = tlkpTrainingType.ID
            ) AS T3

        WHERE T3.TrainingTypeID = ' + @TrainingID + '

        GROUP BY 
        T3.TrainingType,
        T3.TrainingTypeID               
                '

EXECUTE (@query)
```

And here is an example of the result I'm after:

```
TrainingType ¦ TrainingTypeID ¦ CAD ¦ CSD ¦ DVT ¦ FIN ¦ ITS ¦ IWK

HedgeCutter  ¦     200        ¦  0  ¦  2  ¦  0  ¦  7  ¦  1  ¦  0
```

Comment: Please, if you'd like to get an answer, do more effort to make your question easily readable. The guys around should spend time with solving not with hard reading. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised this works at all, since you are concatenating an INT variable and an NVARCHAR(MAX) variable, e.g. If I run:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0,
        @n NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @n = N'This is a test' + @i;
```

I get the error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>
> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'This is a test' to data type int.

In order to apply the filter you may be best off using `sp_executesql` along with a parameter, rather than concatenating your value and using `EXEC`:

So instead of:

```
SET @Query = '....
        WHERE T3.TrainingTypeID = ' + @TrainingID + '
        ...'
EXEC (@Query);
```

You could use:

```
SET @Query = '....
        WHERE T3.TrainingTypeID = @TrainingID
        ...';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query, N'@TrainingID INT', @TrainingID;
```

This is more type safe, means you don't have to cast your int variables to nvarchar to get them into the query and allows for better query plan caching too.

Comment: @ GarethD: It worked originally because there was no filter i.e. it was all NVARCHAR(MAX), no @TrainingID in it at all. But this works great, and most importantly, I understand why - thanks GarethD!

Comment: And sorry for not being clear enough with the formatting guys - just getting to grips with posting ona coding site. Thanks again, though.